# How to make a rails app arrange user posts(events) by date and delete events that have passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, events, date

I set up an event listing site and would like rails to automatically sort these links(events) by date and delete them after the day has passed. After extensive reading, I assume deleting posts that have passed is a cron job. I look forward to any suggestions for that. Right here, I am attempting to list these events by a datetime field in the form. Here's a bit of code.

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
  def new
    authenticate_user!
    @link = Link.new
 end
 def create
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])
```

So in index.html.erb :

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
   <li><%= link_to link.title, link %><br></li>
<%= link_to "comments", link %>
```

And in the new link view I have:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datetime %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :datetime %>
</div>
```

Could I just replace that

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
```

with something like

```
<% @links.where("DATE(datetime) = DATE(?)", DateTime.now)
```

Even just a shove in the right direction would be much appreciated. Though perhaps I need a @links.order_by ?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use something like

```
@links = Link.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Yes, although I didn't want the posts to list by when created, rather the datetime of an event. Maybe just instead of "created_at DESC" I could use something referencing the datetime field attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you are right @pipebender. But its better if you can put the code for your index action in the controller.

```
def index
  @links = Link.where("DATE(datetime) = DATE(?)", DateTime.now).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Comment: This one throws an error undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass from the link view. Instead of ordering by when it was created, I have a field for when the event takes place datetime that I was hoping to order by.